# Marketing Cloud API - Contact Delete Request's status enum

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, contactbuilder

I'm trying to use the delete request API (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ContactsDeleteStatus.htm) 
However I could not found any documents regarding the status values of an Delete Request.
As I tried to explore the API myself, I have some value like `Processing` `Completed` `Invalid` and `Pending`. However I think the list is not completed (at least I'm missing the errors case).

So could anyone provide any documents regarding status of `Delete Request` or possible status of a `Delete Request`?

Comment: I would set the suppression period to 0 days and launch a request

Comment: Hi @jclobro
Thank you for your suggestion, however in my case, `suppression period` is in the post processing phase.
In my case, I need to know whether a `Delete Request` is failed or not. If it fails, I need to retry it through the `Retry Delete Request API` (`https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/RetryContactDelete.htm`). Because I need to ensure the `data integrity` of our data model.
That's why I need to know the possibly status of a `Delete Request` and then could have sufficient action with each kind of status.